# How to pass linmath.h matrices to glsl shader?

Tags: c, opengl, matrix, types, glsl

I'm learning the `linmath.h` library, but I'm having trouble passing matrices made by it in my main program to my vert shader:

```
#include "linmath.h"
…
GLint mat_uniform_handle = glGetUniformLocation(shade_program_handle, "matrix");
…
mat4x4 M;
mat4x4_identity(M);
glUniformMatrix4fv(mat_uniform_handle, 1, GL_FALSE, M);
```

But of course that gives me a type error because `linmath` matrices have the type `float (*)[4]` and `glUniformMatrix4fv` takes the type `const GLfloat *`.

I tried writing my own converter that concated the columns of the matrix into a single array, then returned a pointer to the first element, but that didn't work.

Am I missing some function of `linmath.h` that does this conversion for me? If not, how do I properly convert a `linmath.h` matrix to an opengl matrix?

Answer (score 4):

It's pathetic that I didn't try this before asking here, but here's the solution, just a straight cast.:

```
glUniformMatrix4fv(mat_uniform_handle, 1, GL_FALSE, (GLfloat *)M);
```

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: The intended method, which is also a bit shorter to write is `M[0]` or `*M` – but your's is just fine as well.

Comment: I was having the same problem, and went with your casting solution. My only concern is how safe this is: are 2d arrays guaranteed to have it's sub arrays be consecutive? I.e. does M[1] directly follow M[2] in memory?